# mayavi data not showing until clicking into image

Tags: python, mayavi

I am using `mayavi` to plot some 3D data set as a scatter plot using `mayavi.mlab.points3d`, see the code below. In principle everything works perfectly fine. However, the only thing is that I need to click into the image or rescale the window before the data shows up, i.e. I can only see the blank background. Is there anything that I am missing here or is there any way to update the plot right after generating the figure?

I am using `mayavi` 4.7.2 and Python 3.8 and I have the same problem in PyCharm and jupyter.

```
import mayavi.mlab as mlab

f = mlab.figure()

x = np.linspace(0, 10, 11)
y = x**2
z = y**3

nodes = mlab.points3d(x, y, z)

mlab.show()
```

### Update

When I run my module in the command line I get an error: `QGuiApplication::font(): no QGuiApplication instance and no application font set.`

Comment: Your example works for me (i.e. it shows up immediately). Do you get any warnings when importing mayavi, perhaps after setting `export LIBGL_DEBUG=verbose`?

Comment: @JanWilamowski Thanks for the comment. I have tried it but unfortunately I do not get any message.

Comment: did you export LIBGL_DEBUG in the same shell that starts your IDE? Alternatively, can you reproduce the problem without an IDE in the interactive Python shell?

Comment: I do have the same problem also when I run the code line by line in the shell or when I use ipython.

Comment: This sounds like a problem with the OpenGL installation on your machine. Have you noticed similar issues with other OpenGL software?

Comment: @JanWilamowski I have used 3D plotting in pyqtgraph which uses OpenGL but I did not experience any issues there. However, I have installed pyqtgraph before mayavi so maybe there are some minor conflicts with the different versions.